# Python property object defined outside class __init__

Tags: python, oop, properties

I've been going through Python tutorial for Python properties and I can't make any sense of this code:

```
# using property class
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    # getter
    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    # setter
    def set_temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        if value < -273.15:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273.15 is not possible")
        self._temperature = value

    # creating a property object
    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)


human = Celsius(37)

print(human.temperature)

print(human.to_fahrenheit())

human.temperature = -300
```

1. Why is the property being assigned outside of init?
2. where is `self._temperature` even defined?
3. How is `self._temperature` is linked to `self.temperature` even though these two are not linked together any where in the code?
4. How is it that in the `to_fahrenheit` function, even though that I'm changing `self.temperature`, it is `self._temperature` that gets changed not the original `temperature` that is defined in the constructor?

I'd really appreciate any help since this does not make any sense but works!

Comment: Have you read the `property` documentation?

Comment: Honestly, this example is kinda bad because it mangles the `self.temperature` name (the instance value) with `Celsius.temperature` (the class property) in a way that's not obvious if you don't know about properties beforehand. 99% of the time what you want is to write `self._temperature = temperature` in `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet illustrates the concept of [getter and setter methods in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-in-python/). When attempting to set the `temperature` class variable (e.g. `human.temperature = -300`), Python does not actually modify `human.temperature`, but calls `human.set_temperature(-300)` instead, which, given no error is raised, sets `human._temperature` to the specified value. Similarly, calling `print(human.temperature)` is equivalent to `print(human.get_temperature())` (try these replacements in your code and see what happens).

Moreover, the `_` prefix of `_temperature` signal that it is a [private variable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-variables-python/), i.e. should not be used outside the class definition and the `get_` / `set_` prefix declares that the function is a getter / setter.

In conclusion, `human.temperature` does not hold a value, but rather calls `human.get_temperature()` or `human.set_temperature()` depending on the context. The actual value is stored in `human._temperature`. For a more detailed explanation, I suggest reading the aforementioned articles.